# Understand how slicing works in python and achieve the same using C#

Tags: python, c#, loops, slice

```py
string = "This is a test string. It has 44 characters." #Line1
for i in range(len(string) // 10):                      #Line2
    result= string[10 * i:10 * i + 10]                  #Line3
    print(result)                                       #Line4
```

I want to understand the above code so that I can achieve the same thing using C#

According to my understanding, in Line2:

len(string) counts the length of above string which is 44, dividing by 10 returns 4, [range](https://www.w3schools.com/python/trypython.asp?filename=demo_ref_range)(4) should return: 0,1,2,3 so the `for` loop will run 4 times to print `result`

I confirmed how Line3 works by adding below statements in the python code:

```py
print(string[0:10])
print(string[10:20])
print(string[20:30])
print(string[30:40])
```

The output of both were:

```
This is a 
test strin
g. It has 
44 charact
```

**I tried the below code in C# to achieve the same which didn't print anything:**

```cs
string str = "This is a test string. It has 44 characters.";


            foreach (int i in Enumerable.Range(0, str.Length / 10))
            {
                string result = str[(10*i)..(10*i+10)];
                Console.WriteLine(result);
            }
```

Comment: So what is your question? Is it `how does slicing work in Python?`?

Comment: Confirm if my understanding of python code is correct as mentioned above. If its correct then whats wrong in the way I am trying to do it using C#?

Comment: Related:[Understanding slice notation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/509211/understanding-slice-notation).

Comment: Uhm, your C# code works great on my machine...[check it out on dotnetfiddle.net](https://dotnetfiddle.net/AlobIN)

Comment: Is `str[(10*i)..(10*i+10)]` valid C#? According to the Mono C# compiler version 6.8.0.123 on repli.it it isn't...

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga use C#8.0 or newer

Comment: @JHBonarius yes its working. Just tried with RichTextBox. Not sure why it wasn't printed using `Console`. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

This is how you slice strings in C# with `Substring`:

```
string str = "This is a test string. It has 44 characters.";

foreach (int i in Enumerable.Range(0, str.Length / 10))
{
    var start = 10 * i;
    var end = 10 * i + 10;
    Console.WriteLine(str.Substring(start, end));
}
```

....but you may need to adjust the numbers and check for Index / Out Of Range exceptions.

Answer (score 0):

you just translate the slice method with substring:

```
public string Slice(string source, int start, int end)
{
    if (end < 0) // Keep this for negative end support
    {
        end = source.Length + end;
    }
    int len = end - start;               // Calculate length
    return source.Substring(start, len); // Return Substring of length
}
```

Testing the method:

```
var string = "This is a test string. It has 44 characters."
var result = Slice(string, 0, 10);//give the first tenth chars and so on...
Console.WriteLine(result);
```